# Why we can't assign value to pointer

Tags: c++, pointers

Memory addresses are often displayed in hex formate like `0x7ffff3a9ae94`. Why we can't directly assign these values to pointers?

```
int *ptr=7ffff3a9ae94;
```

A "similar" behavior was shown when i tried this.(This might be a separate question itself)

```
int i=0;
*ptr=&i;
&i=ptr;
```

Both cases show syntax errors on `g++ 4.7.2` which, i assume means its a language restriction.

Why this restriction is implemented in C++?

Or is this some kind of OS limitation?

Note: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/647988/why-cant-i-assign-values-to-pointers) question have similar title but it doesn't provide me answer to my question.

Comment: Because `int *ptr=7ffff3a9ae94;` is invalid syntax.

Comment: It doesn't make a sence to hardcode address of pointer to **dynamic** memory.

Comment: You cannot store a hex value like `7ffff3a9ae94` in an `int` . There are some protocols to be followed or you need to create one and make sure others follow too.

Comment: Pointers work like other variables/types in the sense that they hold a value as well. They work differently in the sense that the value they hold is an address in memory. You cannot hardcode a memory address, getting a free block of memory is an operation which has to be requested to the OS.

Comment: @yanivx: The main problem would be that `int` might not be big enough, but "hex value" has nothing to do with it. `0x7fff` will always fit.

Answer (score 2):

there is no such rule , this :

`int *ptr=(int*)0x7ffff3a9ae94;`

compiles fine.
although it's a bad thing to to.

intresting fact : the idea that you can convert pointer to integer and vice versa is one of the biggest blocks when talking about garbage collector in C++ in general. you can (althoug it's stupid) to serialize the memory address in some external buffer, then re-assign it to some pointer. the GC may think it can delete the variable because nowone else points at it - while the pointer is still "valid" and will be dereference somewhere in the future

Comment: C++11 addresses that GC problem. See [`std::pointer_safety`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/gc/pointer_safety)